# Why control is going inside if condition while the condition is false

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Function to find minimum number of eliminations such that sum of all adjacent elements is even:

```
def min_elimination(n, arr): 
    countOdd = 0

    # Stores the new value 
    for i in range(n): 

        # Count odd numbers 
       ***if (arr[i] % 2): 
              countOdd += 1***

    # Return the minimum of even and 
    # odd count 
    return min(countOdd, n - countOdd) 

# Driver code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9] 
    n = len(arr) 
    print(min_elimination(n, arr))
```

Please help me with the `if` condition. When the code does `if(number%2)` then control is going inside the `if` since the first element of list is an odd number. Is there any difference between `if(number%2`) and `if(number%2==0)`. Because when I tried `if(number%2==0)` control didn't go inside the `if` as the number was odd (check first element of the list).

Answer (score 0):

The only way two integers can add up to be even is that both integers should be odd, or both integers should be even.

So your question basically wants to find whether there are more odd number in the array, or even numbers:

```
def min_elimination(arr):
    return len(min([n for n in arr if n%2],[n for n in arr if not n%2],key=len))

print(min_elimination([1, 2, 3, 7, 9]))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Your answer is looking good. Just one doubt though, probably it is missing the keyword "adjacent elements". In your solution, 1, 3, 7, 9 are not all adjacent because there is an element 2 in between 1 and 3! Am I right?

Comment: @Ketan You have a good point, but the post did not specify that after an elimination, we should leave a gap between the two numbers adjacent to the eliminated one.

Comment: It's sort of like the method `remove()`, after an element is removed from the list, the gap is closed by the surrounding elements. Am I right?

Comment: @Ann Zen. Yes after use of remove the gap is closed automatically.So they become adjacent even after deletion of an element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version of the above.

```py
def min_elimination(arr):
    lst1 = [n for n in arr if n%2] # List of all odd numbers
    lst2 = [n for n in arr if not n%2] # List of all even numbers
    lst = max(lst1, lst2, key=lambda x: len(x))
    return lst
print(min_elimination([1, 2, 3, 7, 9]))
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP describes nor answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code works fine as-is.  It correctly returns the minimum number of eliminations necessary to achieve the result, not the result itself.

> is there any difference between if(number%2) and if(number%2==0)

Yes, `if number % 2` is the same as saying `if number % 2 == 1`, which is the opposite of saying `if number % 2 == 0`.  So switching one for the other will break your program's logic.

I might simplify your code as follows:

```
def min_elimination(array): 
    odd = 0

    # Stores the new value 
    for number in array: 

        # Count odd numbers 
        odd += number % 2

    return min(odd, len(array) - odd)
```

Where `min_elimination([1, 2, 3, 7, 9])` returns `1`, there is one (1) elimination necessary to make the sum of all adjacent elements even.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to compare the number of odd numbers in the array to the number of even numbers in the array:

```
import numpy as np

def min_elimination(arr):
    return len(min(arr[arr%2],arr[any(arr%2)],key=len))

print(min_elimination(np.array([1, 2, 3, 7, 9])))
```

Output:

```
1
```